# How to perform migrations in the package manager?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, fluent-migrator

I installed FluentMigration to manage my SQL files.

In the package management I execute the following commands:

```
PM> dotnet add package FluentMigrator
PM> dotnet add package FluentMigrator.Runner
```

## Migration

```
 [Migration(201805041513)]
    public class _201805041513_CriacaoTabelaPessoa : ForwardOnlyMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Create.Table("Pessoa")
                .InSchema("angularCore")
                .WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().Identity()
                .WithColumn("Nome").AsString(80)
                .WithColumn("SobreNome").AsString(50)
                .WithColumn("Email").AsString(50)
                .WithColumn("IdTpoPessoa").AsInt16()
                .WithColumn("IdEndereco").AsInt16();


        }
    }
```

**Out-of-process (for some corporate requirements)**

```
PM> dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli
```

Error:

> No executable found corresponding to the "dotnet-tool" command

## [Documentation](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-dotnet-fm)

## Edit

Run in

```
PM> dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli
PM> dotnet fm migrate -p sqlite -c "Data Source=test.db" -a ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"
```

Generate **teste.db**

[image]

> In the old versions you run the migrations directly in the database, I
>   did not understand how to update my database, ie create the Person
>   table through the generated test.db file?

Comment: According to the documentation you need to be using at minimum the .NET Core 2.1 preview 2 SDK for this tool. Are you using .NET Core 2.1 preview 2? I believe you can check by running dotnet --version. You should get back 2.1.300-p2 if using preview 2 which was release Apr 11, 2018

Comment: @Matt Running in package Managment: PM> dotnet --version Result: 2.1.103

Comment: You need to install the latest preview. The dotnet tool command is new to 2.1-preview 2 https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview2

Comment: @Matt I was able to perform the migration, should it not be run in my database?

Comment: If you ran the migration In-Process and did not receive any errors the table should be there. If it is not there the Services may not be configured correctly. Please edit your post to show how you are configuring the Services. If you ran Out Of Process via the command line please post the command line you used as well. My previous comments were regarding the dotnet tool error.

Comment: @Matt issue edited

Comment: I created a test project and was able to run your migration without any issues. The steps I took are in the Answer Below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this to work without any issues. Here is what I did:

First I installed .NET Core 2.1-Preview 2. After installing I verified the version:

```
dotnet --version
2.1.300-preview2-008533
```

I then created the project

```
mkdir testfm
cd testfm
dotnet new console
```

Installed the nuget packages

```
dotnet add package FluentMigrator
dotnet add package FluentMigrator.Runner
dotnet add package FluentMigrator.Runner.SQLite
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
```

Installed the CLI tool

```
dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli
```

Created a Migration Class called Migration1.cs

```
     using FluentMigrator;

namespace test
{
    [Migration(201805041513)]
    public class _201805041513_CriacaoTabelaPessoa : ForwardOnlyMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Create.Table("Pessoa")
                .InSchema("angularCore")
                .WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().Identity()
                .WithColumn("Nome").AsString(80)
                .WithColumn("SobreNome").AsString(50)
                .WithColumn("Email").AsString(50)
                .WithColumn("IdTpoPessoa").AsInt16()
                .WithColumn("IdEndereco").AsInt16();


        }
    }
}
```

Compiled the project

```
dotnet build
```

Ran the migration from the root project directory

> dotnet fm migrate -p sqlite -c "Data Source=test.db" -a
>   ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"

I then Received the following messages.
[image: Sucess FM Run]

I then confirmed the table was created by viewing the SqlLite DB

[image: SqlLite DB View]

To run this same migration on a Sql Server 2016 you would run:

> dotnet fm migrate -p SqlServer2016 -c
>   "server=SQLSERVERINSTANCE;uid=testfm;pwd=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=FluentMigrator"
>   -a ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"

Comment: And how would that run in a local mssql database?

Comment: It depends on what SQL version you are targeting. To get a full list of processors available you can run "dotnet fm list processors" If you were targeting SqlServer 2016 you would run your command like 'dotnet fm migrate -p SqlServer2016 -c "server=SQLSERVERINSTANCE;uid=testfm;pwd=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=FluentMigrator" -a ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"'

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you add a connection string in the response?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to show the connection string / command for sql server 2016